# Bivariate Data Variables

Tags: dataset, bivariate

When comparing two different variables to determine whether or not one determines the other, do both data sets of the variables need to be from the same year? Such as life expectancy from 2004 and HDI from 2015, is this valid?

Comment: It depends on the question. What is HDI ? Is your question: Does life expectancy from 2004 cause HDI from 2015 ? In this case, yes.

Comment: Is your question: Does life expectancy concomitantly cause HDI? In this case, I imagine you should rather get data for the same years. In the hypothetical case you  cannot, then this might probably have a sense for instance if most of the variation is essentially cross-sectional (inter-countries) and not temporal (inter-years), so that the 2015 values are good approximations of the 2004 values.

Comment: And in the end, you should be aware that this is just a correlation, so just run it and precisely describe which correlation you get.

Comment: Oh right, so it will still have a correlation, however, it is not accurate?